# EC2 instance i-####### is not in the same VPC as ELB using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I'm having trouble doing test with Terraform. I'm newbie in both AWS and Terraform technologies. I'm trying to create some webservers under a Load Balancer.

To achieve this I've created:

VPC, subnets, Internet Gateway and Route table:

```
resource "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
  cidr_block = "${var.cidr}"
  enable_dns_hostnames = false
  enable_dns_support = false
  tags = {
    Name = "vpc-${var.project}"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "pub1" {
  cidr_block = "${var.pub1_cidr}"
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.vpc.id}"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
  availability_zone = "${data.aws_availability_zones.az.names[0]}"
  tags = {
    Name = "${var.project}-subnetpub1"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "pub2" {
  cidr_block = "${var.pub2_cidr}"
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.vpc.id}"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
  availability_zone = "${data.aws_availability_zones.az.names[1]}"
  tags = {
    Name = "${var.project}-subnetpub2"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "pri1" {
  cidr_block = "${var.pri1_cidr}"
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.vpc.id}"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
  availability_zone = "${data.aws_availability_zones.az.names[0]}"
  tags = {
    Name = "${var.project}-subnet1"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "pri2" {
  cidr_block = "${var.pri2_cidr}"
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.vpc.id}"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
  availability_zone = "${data.aws_availability_zones.az.names[1]}"
  tags = {
    Name = "${var.project}-subnet2"
  }
}

resource "aws_internet_gateway" "igw" {
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.vpc.id}"
}

resource "aws_route" "default_route" {
  route_table_id = "${aws_vpc.vpc.default_route_table_id}"
  destination_cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
  gateway_id = "${aws_internet_gateway.igw.id}"
}
```

Security Groups:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "elb-sg" {
  name = "elb-sg"
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id

  # Entrada
  ingress {
    from_port = 80
    protocol = "tcp"
    to_port = 80
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  # Salida
  egress {
    from_port = 0
    protocol = "-1"
    to_port = 0
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "elb-web" {
  name = "web-sg"
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id

  ingress {
    from_port = 80
    protocol = "tcp"
    to_port = 80

    # Permitimos el acceso a este security group a aquellos recursos que tengan asigando el security group de elb
    security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.elb-sg.id}"]
  }
  egress {
    from_port = 0
    protocol = "-1"
    to_port = 0
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}
```

And finally the ELB and the EC2 instances:

```
resource "aws_elb" "elbweb" {
  name = "elb-${var.project}-${var.environment}" # Nombre del balanceador.
  cross_zone_load_balancing = true # Balancear entre las zonas
  subnets = ["${aws_subnet.pub1.id}","${aws_subnet.pub2.id}"]
  security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.elb-sg.id}"]

  listener {
    instance_port = 80
    instance_protocol = "http"
    lb_port = 80
    lb_protocol = "http"
  }

  availability_zones = "${data.aws_availability_zones.az.names}"
  instances = "${aws_instance.webservers.*.id}"
}

resource "aws_instance" "webservers" {
  instance_type = "${var.instance_type}"
  ami = "${lookup(var.aws_amis, var.region)}"
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.elb-web.id}"]
  subnet_id = "${aws_subnet.pri1.id}"

  count = 3

  tags = {
    Name = "VM${var.environment}WEBSERVER${count.index}"
  }
}
```

When I try to `apply`, I'm getting the following errror:

```
aws_elb.elbweb: Modifying... [id=elb-web-project-development]
╷
│ Error: Failure registering instances with ELB: InvalidInstance: EC2 instance i-0a39df0625ab87dd1 is not in the same VPC as ELB.
│       status code: 400, request id: c0f700b4-50a7-42af-af9a-a5690509b6cb
│ 
│   with aws_elb.elbweb,
│   on elb.tf line 1, in resource "aws_elb" "elbweb":
│    1: resource "aws_elb" "elbweb" {
│ 
╵
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you really want to be using an [ELB classic](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/introduction.html)? If you're running a web server behind it the normal thing would be to use an [application load balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/introduction.html) which uses the [`aws_lb` resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lb) instead.

Comment: Your code also has a lot of unnecessary interpolation (eg `"${var.instance_type}"` instead of `var.instance_type`). Are you copying things from very old guides? Your error message makes it look like you are using a newish version of Terraform and you've tagged it with `terraform0.12+` which suggests you aren't using a version of Terraform older than 0.12 so you can ditch that interpolation. `terraform fmt` should handle that for you with a newish version of Terraform

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Yes, I'm using old docs but I thought it would not be a problem, I am learning and for basic concepts I thought it was enough. I will review what you tell me. In any case, I don't understand the downvote

Comment: Down vote isn't from me. The question has a lot of information in it so I wouldn't down vote that. I was confused by the usage of a long deprecated-ish thing (the classic load balancer) and the pre 0.12 syntax for learning Terraform now though. I'd probably start with newer guides/resources if you want to pick up Terraform. I'd recommend https://learn.hashicorp.com/terraform.

Comment: Anyway, I think the error is showing that the ELB and instance were both created but it just failed to attach the instance. In that case you should be able to describe them both with the AWS CLI (eg `aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids ...` and `aws elbv2 describe-load-balancers --load-balancer-arns ...`) and edit your question to include the output of those.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a resource `aws_lb_target_group` and then another resource `aws_lb_target_group_attachment` with the instance attached to it.

Also, the resource `elbweb` should have a default action which points the listener to the target group.

Looking at your code for the resources `pri1` and `pri2`, are those subnets intended to be private? If yes, shouldn't the attribute `map_public_ip_on_launch` be set to `false`?

Update:

Figured it out. Sorry it took me a while as I was busy.
I ran the code you posted. Encountered the same error `... not in the same VPC..`, but I made the code to work after tweaking.

You can comment out the `availability_zones` in the resource `aws_elb` and `cross_zone_load_balancing`. This did the trick for me.

```
resource "aws_elb" "elb_web" {
  name                      = "elb-${var.project_name}"
  subnets                   = [aws_subnet.pub1.id, aws_subnet.pub2.id]
  security_groups           = [aws_security_group.elb-sg.id]
  # cross_zone_load_balancing = true

  listener {
    instance_port     = 80
    instance_protocol = "http"
    lb_port           = 80
    lb_protocol       = "http"
  }

  # availability_zones = []
  instances            = aws_instance.webservers.*.id
}
```

As per Terraform documentation, for resource `aws_elb`, `cross_zone_load_balancing` by default is `true`. So, you don't have to explicitly set the attribute to `true`. Since this attribute is enabled, I assume specifying `availability_zones` causes confusion.

I ran with two EC2s in the private subnet and I could see that the same were attached to the ELB.

I hope this works for you.

Comment: They're using an ELB classic (see `aws_elb` in the question).

Comment: Updated my answer. Not sure about the formatting of the code while commenting here. So, please check it out. And, it's a good question! Learnt something new from this :)